# Distinct and Sorted results in Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I am trying to use Apache Solr to create a product catalog.  Let's say I have three fields that are indexed as Solr facets:

```
* SKU
* Color
* Price
```

Let's say this is what my indexed data looks like:

SKU  / Color  /  Price

```
1. Foo / Blue  / 2.00
2. Bar / Red   / 3.50
3. Foo / Red   / 1.00
4. Bar / Green / 5.00
```

I want a query that returns `limit=1` on SKU and the lowest prices.  Thus rows 2 & 3 above.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you will be able to achieve this with just one query in Solr

First you will execute this query to get list of all SKU as facets

```
http://localhost:8080/select/?facet=on&facet.field=SKU&rows=0&q=*:*
```

Then you will have to iterate through the results using PHP or some language, and for each SKU, you can send following query to Solr to get lowest price for that SKU

```
http://localhost:8080/jobs/select/?fq=SKU:$sku&rows=1&q=*:*&sort=price asc
```

Total number of Solr requests will be: n+1, where 1 is for initial request to get list of all SKUs, and then n more, where n is number of unique SKUs.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by SKU and sort by price to get one product per SKU with the lowest price.

Something like `group=on&group.field=SKU&group.sort=price asc`

For more details, see [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) page on the Solr Wiki.